# Pausing across multiple view controllers, what does -> do?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

a few noobie questions here first time ever I've tried to pause a Scene/Nodes hoping someone can please help me understand what is happening.

I have 2 VC's
GameViewController.m (contains my GameUI related code)
GameScene.m (contains my gameplay related code and my main node called "myWorld").

From GameViewController.m 
If I run

```
_scene.paused = YES;
```

everything is paused on the screen by the looks of it and nothing moves, but if I unpause the game via

```
_scene.paused = NO;
```

you can tell my GameScene.m "myWorld" node has continued to run because when I unpause the game goes into super fast forward and catches up to the position it would have been if I did not pause.

I tried a few other lines like

```
self.view.paused = YES;
```

then Xcode suggested that I change to

```
self->_skView.paused = YES;
```

When I did this it works! and successfully paused all of the contents including the "myWorld" code inside GameScene.m. But how? I don't understand?
Can someone please tell me what does "->" do here???

Also in my other VC GameScene.m I have a line of code in my update method that is waiting for the game to paused via

```
if (self.paused==YES)
```

but when I run this new code from GameViewController.m  "self->_skView.paused = YES;"

that if (self.paused==YES) "if" condition is not met inside here.

```
GameScene.m
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
if (self.paused==YES) {
//do stuff
```

How do I write that the "if" condition so that when  GameViewController.m "self->_skView.paused = YES;" the "if" condition is met in GameScene.m?

I guess what I am asking is how do I talk from one VC to the other? Or how do I tell both VC's properly that the game is paused etc?

Any help would be great my code below

```
GameViewController.m

@implementation GameViewController {
SKView *_skView; 
GameScene *_scene; 
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

if (!_skView) {
    _skView =
    [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    GameScene *scene =
    [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:_skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [_skView presentScene:scene];
    [self.view addSubview:_skView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_skView];

    _scene = scene;
    __weak GameViewController *weakSelf = self;
}
}

//My pause method
//was    
//_scene.paused = YES;
//now
self->_skView.paused = YES;

//My unpause method
//was    
//_scene.paused = NO;
//now
self->_skView.paused = NO;

GameScene.m

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
SKNode *myWorld = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:myWorld];

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
if (self.paused==YES) {
//do stuff
```

Comment: The scene's update methods keep on being called when you only pause the scene. If you pause the view it'll pause everything. Provided that you used only Sprite Kit timing methods, not NSTimer, performSelector:afterDelay: or dispatch_ methods for timing.

Comment: You could check in the start of the update.  `if(yourScene.paused) return;`

Comment: Can you please explain what the main issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid creating an instance variable (ivar) for your `SKScene` subclass. If you don't set the ivar to nil at some point, SpriteKit won't release the scene when you transition to another scene. Also, you don't need the ivar for the `SKView`, since you can access it through `self`. Here's an example of how to pause the SKView from the view controllers and scene subclasses:

In your view controllers,

pause the `SKView` with

```
((SKView *)self.view).paused = YES;
```

and check if the view is paused with

```
if (((SKView *).self.view).paused) {
   // Do something
}
```

In your `SKScene` subclasses (e.g., `GameScene`),

pause the `SKView` with

```
self.view.paused = YES;
```

and to check if the view is paused with

```
if (self.view.paused) {
   // Do something
}
```

You can use the delegation mechanism to tell a view controller to pause its view or ask a VC if its view is paused.